# Importar JSON para tabela MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, json

Estou tentando importar um JSON para o MySQL, porém sem sucesso

EDIT: O JSON tem a estrutura abaixo, é retorno [dessa query sparql da wikidata](https://w.wiki/52i). A query criou um documento para cada tupla

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d02f06243ced42c10bd28dc"),
    "tipoLinguagem" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q9143",
    "tipoLinguagemLabel" : "programming language",
    "subtipoLinguagem" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3839507",
    "subtipoLinguagemLabel" : "functional programming language",
    "linguagem" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2005",
    "linguagemLabel" : "JavaScript",
    "wd" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P127",
    "wdLabel" : "owned by",
    "ps" : "http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/P127",
    "ps_Label" : "Oracle Corporation",
    "isIdentifier" : "false"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d02f06243ced42c10bd28dd"),
    "tipoLinguagem" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q9143",
    "tipoLinguagemLabel" : "programming language",
    "subtipoLinguagem" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1993334",
    "subtipoLinguagemLabel" : "interpreted language",
    "linguagem" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2005",
    "linguagemLabel" : "JavaScript",
    "wd" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P127",
    "wdLabel" : "owned by",
    "ps" : "http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/P127",
    "ps_Label" : "Sun Microsystems",
    "isIdentifier" : "false"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d02f06143ced42c10bd27af"),
    "tipoLinguagem" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q9143",
    "tipoLinguagemLabel" : "programming language",
    "subtipoLinguagem" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q3839507",
    "subtipoLinguagemLabel" : "functional programming language",
    "linguagem" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q2005",
    "linguagemLabel" : "JavaScript",
    "wd" : "http://www.wikidata.org/entity/P571",
    "wdLabel" : "inception",
    "ps" : "http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/P571",
    "ps_Label" : "1995-12-04T00:00:00Z",
    "isIdentifier" : "false"
}
```

O que preciso é consultar banco para trazer objetos como:

```
{
  languageName: 'Javascript',
  paradigms: [
      function, scripting, etc
  ]
  props: [
     owned by: value,
     inception: value
     etc...
  ]
}
E também um objeto para os paradigmas

{
  paradigm: functional programming
  languages: javascript, curl, etc...
}
```

Como devem ser criadas as tabela? Cada exemplo que encontrei usa um método diferente, e não consegui com nenhum deles.

Queria algo simples como o mogoimport.

**Não consegui instalar o workbench no Ubuntu 19.04, nem pelo terminal nem pela loja

** Todo o JSON fica numa coluna só? Isso parece muito errado...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lings_json( 
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    json_data JSON NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que seria útil saber o que está no "q3.json"

Comment: Editei lá, pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O banco MySQL não é o ideal para essa sua solução. O que você consegue fazer com ele é criar uma coluna do tipo json (somente mysql versão 5.7 ou superior se não me engano) que serve para armazenar um objeto tipo Json (útil para quando temos um objeto tipo endereço por exemplo, onde não se sabe quantos parâmetros vão ser preenchidos). Porém ele não te proporciona funcionalidades como busca avançada para realizar nos SELECTS. Então basicamente você fica extremamente limitado quando precisar procurar coisas dentro de um objeto json. O uso que temos de json para MySQL é somente trazer objeto, ficando cargo da aplicação fazer desdobramento desse objeto, (serializar, deserializar). Se quer realizar procuras e coisas avançadas dentro de um Json, é utilizar MongoDB ou outro banco que possua suporte a isso. Ou até utilizar os dois bancos, MySQL para cuidar de relacionamentos colocando um chave para um objetivo do Mongo por exemplo.

Comment: então, eu comecei usando o mongo. mas na pergunta abaixo me disseram que seria melhor um bd relacional https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/391454/modelar-base-de-dados

Comment: sem querer abusar, poderia me ajudar com as dúvidas dessa outra questão? eu só trabalhei com Oracle por enquanto, estou tendo dificuldade em manipular os dados pelo mongo/mongoose.

Comment: Então o problema é justamente esse, primeiro você tem que definir, o meu problema é relacional? A informações são estruturadas? 
Se os dados são estruturados, você utiliza SGBD relacional, Oracle, MySQL, Postgree, etc. Porém se os seus dados maioria é não estruturado, ai você ja parte para um Mongo da vida. Exemplo: Tenho um dado endereço, porém ele tem várias maneiras, As vezes tem bloco, complemento, referência, etc. Se você jogar NULL em tudo, você perde desempenho e disco... por isso temos soluções como Mongo para tratar dados não estruturados.

Comment: Mongo é extremamente simples, não tem isso de chave primeira, estrangeira, relacionamento nem nada ele é como se fosse um arquivo texto gigante, porem possui as "funções" prontas para seleção de dados e procura. Dependendo da biblioteca tipo o mogoose é extremamente simples fazer uma seleção, a sintaxe é infinitivamente mais simples que o de um SQL. O exemplo que você passou os dados estão estruturados (tem um padrão), então é possível usar SGBD relacional, cada atributo do objeto, tipoLinguagem, tipoLinguagemLabel, etc...  voce faz virar uma coluna, e insere os dados.

Comment: sim, terei que criar vários inserts... estava procurando uma solução como o mongoimport, mas vou ter que deixar a preguiça de lado